# Missing Power Bi calculated columns after moving data location

Tags: powerbi

I’ve had to migrate a working Power Bi solution from one vm to another. In the process I have zipped up the xcel spreadsheets and pbix files.

On the target machine the folder structure of the spreadsheets have changed - the machine name
was hard coded into filepaths. So I have changed the source for each query to point to the moved xcel spreadsheet and the majority of queries load.

There are some queries with calculated columns which won’t load. PowerBi states that the calculated column is no longer present.

I can go back a couple of stages in the transformation and the data appears in those queries that fail to load. I can also look in the advanced query editor and it references the calculated column.

Has the migration broken these calculated columns?

Comment: Proper reference to the new file (with same structure) should recalculate all custom columns just as previous. I just tested it here :)

Comment: I believe this turned out to be an error in the original report.

Comment: What do you mean by original report? If file structure is exact same, change of file location should not make any issue.

Comment: I think the original report must have had errors, but I couldn't test this because I had to first change all of the dataset locations. No access to the original report.